How to get PHP-FPM error.log in same directory as PHP script causing the error?
Under one of my domains I have 2 directories where different PHP scripts run, like so:
domain/directory1/
domain/directory2/
My goal is to have a separate PHP error.log file in each directory.  If a script in directory1 cause an error then I want the error to appear in domain/directory1/error_log
And if a script in directory2 cause an error then I want the error to appear in domain/directory2/error_log
My server runs AlmaLinux 9.4 and PHP 9.3
I edited the file system_pool_defaults.yaml by adding the following line.
php_admin_value_error_log: {name: 'php_value[error_log]', value: '"[% documentroot %]/error2.log"'}
Note the single quote at the start and end of the string.
I saved the yaml file and ran the script
/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/php_fpm_config  --rebuild
and then restarted apache and PHP-FPM
Then I ran a PHP script in directory1 that causes an error.
The file error2.log was created at:
domain/error2.log
Is there some directive I can put in my system_pool_defaults.yaml file (or other technique) that will result in separate PHP error.log files in both directory1 and directory2?
